# AngularJS [$injector:modulerr] no mod 'testApp' is not available

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testApp">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.29/angular.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="TileController" class="finder-info-square">
          // code....  
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is my Javascript file:

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module("testApp", []);

    var TileController = function($scope){
       // do stuff....
    };

    app.controller("TileController", ["$scope", TileController]);
})();
```

And this is the error I keep getting...

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module testApp due to:
>   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'testApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Does anybody know why this error is occurring? I'm trying to create my own testApp module, but for some reason it keeps throwing this error when creating the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include your javascript file as well as the angular library

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.29/angular.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/myscript.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh man I'm such an idiot. I completely forgot about adding in my source file. Thanks! :D